# How to Move billing address to below shipping address form in onestep checkout (IWD_opc)?

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address, onestepcheckout

How to Move billing address to below shipping address form in onestep checkout (IWD_opc) ?

We can move billing address section in shipping address area in Magento default checkout but not working same code for IWD_Opc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Magento 2: Placing Billing Address Right Under Shipping Address In Checkout](https://www.tigren.com/billing-under-shipping-address-m2/)

Above link helped me to crack this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below extension given here in my blog:

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-improvedcheckout.html

Tested and worked with 2.4.5

[image]
[image]